# Singular oder Plural für Zeiten

Tags: grammar, verb, time

Im Englischen gibt es eine Regel, dass für Zeiten (und Länge, Geldbetrag, usw.) das singuläre Verb verwendet werden soll (z.B. [Regel 8 hier](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)).

> Five years **is** the maximum sentence for that offense.

Wie läuft das im Deutschen? Funktioniert es mehr oder weniger gleich?

> Fünf Jahre **ist** die maximale Strafe für dieses Vergehen.

(Ich habe im Google "singular oder plural für Zeiten" gesucht, aber keine hilfreichen Ergebnisse bekommen.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aus meiner Sicht gehen beide Konstruktionen, die Bedeutung verschiebt sich ganz leicht, je nach Fall:

- Fünf Jahre **ist** eine lange Zeit. -> Bedeutung: Ein Zeit*raum* / ein Zeit*block* (als "Einheit" gesehen)
- Fünf Jahre **sind** eine lange Zeit. -> Bedeutung: eine bestimmte Anzahl ("zählbare" Einheiten)

Das deckt sich auch mit Regel 8 aus Deinem Link ("Use singular verb ... when considered as a unit").

Comment: @Thorsten deine Begründung ist nicht Korrekt. Nur weil der Zeitraum nicht explizit ausgesprochen (oder ausgeschrieben) wird , heisst das nicht, dass er nicht da ist. Außerdem sagt der Deutsche auch "Die Leute sind" was kümmert es den Engländer? Warum ist dein 'the police are' als Gegenbeispiel relevant?

Comment: @Stephie: Inwiefern ist es relevant, ob sich die deutsche Grammatik mit der englischen deckt? Deutsche Grammatik <> Englische Grammatik.

Comment: Siehe dazu auch http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_id=3150 . Dort lautet das Fazit "Beide Varianten sind gebräuchlich. Für beide gibt es gute Gründe."

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Nur insofern als der OP fragte, ob es im Deutschen "mehr oder weniger gleich" sei.

Comment: Also auch "250 Studenten geht auf die Straße um für bessere Bedingungen zu demonstrieren"?

Comment: @matthias Dieses Fazit bezieht sich auf das Beispiel "Die Mehrheit der Studenten blieb/blieben zuhause". In diesem Fall hinkt das ein bisschen. Die Begründung ist, dass man sich im einen Fall auf die Mehrheit bezieht, in dem anderen Fall auf die Stundenten. Das passt in diesem Beispiel mit "Fünf Jahre ist/sind eine lange Zeit" nur bedingt.

Comment: Ich betrachte 250 Studenten nicht als "Einheit", sondern als Individuen. Aber Matthias' Link beschreibt das m.E. ausführlich genug. Und wir sind uns wahrscheinlich einig, daß bei Abweichungen in der Singular/Plural-Konstellation eine kontextuelle Begründung / Bedeutungsverschiebung nötig ist, wenngleich manchmal nur "im Hintergrund". Ob eine solche Formulierung "schön ist" ist eine ganz andere Frage. Ich bevorzuge i.a. die Angleichung, kann aber in manchen Fällen die Abweichung nachvollziehen.

Comment: Ich habe Matthias' Link auch gelesen, denn er hat ihn von mir :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Den Verweis auf das IDS Mannheim habe ich von Dir, aber auf der konkreten Seite war ich, bevor ich Deinen inzwischen gelöschten Kommentar gelesen hatte. Im übrigen bin ich der Meinung, dass es dort allgemein um Grenzbereiche der Subjekt-Verb-Kongruenz bezüglich Numerus geht und "Mehrzahl der Studenten" nur das titelgebende Beispiel ist.

Comment: @Matthias Hier geht es um Sätze mit einem Subjekt, bestehend aus einem singularen und einem pluralen Anteil (Beispiele: *die Mehrzahl der Stundenten*, *eine Herde Schafe*, *ein Teller Plätzchen*). Daher ist dieser Link meiner Meinung nach auf den Satz "5 Jahre sind eine lange Zeit" nicht anwendbar, da hier das Subjekt ausschließlich im Plural steht und keine singularen Anteil hat.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Stimmt, was den Fokus des Links betrifft. Deshalb schrieb ich auch "Siehe auch". Unmittelbar vor dem Fazit steht dort: _"Eine Rolle spielt wohl zudem, ob eine Herde Schafe als etwas Singulares, eine kompakte Einheit, oder als etwas Plurales, eine wuselnde Vielzahl, wahrgenommen wird. Es ist wie bei einem Kippbild: Mal sieht das Auge das eine, mal das andere."_ Das trifft hier mMn ebenfalls zu.

Comment: Ähnlich argumentieren auch [der Duden](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/newsletter/duden-newsletter-vom-18-05-12) und [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mengenangabe-49575).

Answer (score 5):

Wenn eine Maß- oder Mengenangabe das Subjekt des Satzes bildet, dann besteht laut *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* heute besonders in der Alltags- und Umgangssprache die Neigung, das Verb in die Singularform zu setzen, auch wenn das Zahlwort nicht eins ist. Zahl und Gezähltes werden dann als Einheit verstanden. Standardsprachlich korrekt ist hier nur der Plural:

> Fünf Jahre reichen nicht aus.
> *umgangssprachlich auch:* Fünf Jahre reicht nicht aus.

Allerdings sind bei einem Kopulaverb wie *sein* und einem Prädikativ im Singular beide Möglichkeiten standardsprachlich korrekt:

> Fünf Jahre sind lang.
> Fünf Jahre ist lang.
>
> Fünf Jahre sind eine lange Zeit.
> Fünf Jahre ist eine lange Zeit.
>
> Fünf Jahre sind die maximale Strafe für dieses Vergehen.
> Fünf Jahre ist die maximale Strafe für dieses Vergehen.

Folgt einer Angabe mit *Stunde, Tag, Monat, Jahr* usw. im Plural eine Tätigkeitsbeschreibung im Singular, so kann das Verb sowohl im Singular als auch im Plural stehen:

> Fünf Jahre Schuften hat sich gelohnt.
> Fünf Jahre Schuften haben sich gelohnt.
>
> Fünf Jahre Warten war umsonst.
> Fünf Jahre Warten waren umsonst.